# set Nivo Slider path to absolute

Tags: jquery, wordpress, absolute-path, nivo-slider

I am using the jQuery Nivo Slider plugin in Wordpress (but not the Wordpress Plugin of the same name) with custom posts, it works perfectly and is simple as pie, EXCEPT it is adding the site root to the image path. I am pulling in an absolute path for my image

```
http://www.site.com/images/image.jpg
```

but Nivo is prepending the site root to the path, which generates:

```
www.site.com/http://www.site.com/images/image.jpg
```

I can't find an option in Nivo's documentation to set it to take an absolute path... any ideas??

Here is my template code:

```
            <?php global $post;
                 $myposts = get_posts('post_type=homepageslider&numberposts=4&order=asc');
                 foreach($myposts as $post) :
                 setup_postdata($post);?>


                <a href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" data-thumb="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" /></a>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

a few comments:

- print_r shows 'image' is echoing this exact path: http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg (which is correct)
- when pulled out of the slide code, that loop generates the 4 images perfectly fine with no broken image icon.
- I tried using a Nivo Slider WP plugin and it worked fine but gave the same issue: broken path, broken link icon (even though the image was loading).

Below is the rendered HTML from the browser. As you can see, the "current slide" path is fine. The problem is with the content in the nivo-slice divs: it's adding an extra root to them. This is the SAME issue I had when using the plugin without any of my custom posts or fields.

```
<a class="nivo-imageLink" href="http://www.mysite.com/products/product1/" style="display: none;">
<a class="nivo-imageLink" href="http://www.mysite.com/products/product2/" style="display: none;">
<a class="nivo-imageLink" href="http://www.mysite.com/products/product3/" style="display: none;">
<a class="nivo-imageLink" href="http://www.mysite.com/products/product4/" style="display: block;">
<img class="nivo-main-image" src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg" style="display: inline; height: 377px;">

<div class="nivo-caption"></div>

<div class="nivo-slice" name="0" style="left: 0px; width: 971px; height: 377px; opacity: 1; overflow: hidden;">
    <img style="position:absolute; width:971px; height:auto; display:block !important; top:0; left:-0px;" src="www.mysite.com/http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg">
</div>
```

(and the div nivo-slice is repeated [name from 0 - 14] with the different slides)

Here is the error being generated in the console (Repeating every time the slider rotates)

```
GET http://www.mysite.com/http:/www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg 404 (Not Found) /http:/www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg:1
GET http://www.mysite.com/http:/www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

*Another Update:* I took the wordpress loop out completely and put in 4 static image links. The rotator works fine, shows the images fine, but is having the same issue, broken image icon and prepending the site url to the existing path.

Comment: Please post some code. Markup would help.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440905/nivo-slider-red-x-icon-appearing-over-images-in-ie

Comment: if you are not using the wordpress plugin and using the jQuery plugin you control where it pulls the images from not wordpress :/

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I added all of my markup and notes on my troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: @CBroe: I deleted the duplicate (I left it up because I initially thought it was a different problem and thought my solution could help someone else who was also mistaken about the true problem)

Comment: @DavidChase it is pulling the correct path, but someplace in the plugin it is adding an extra path to the beginning of my path..

Comment: is this a wordpress plugin?

Comment: @DavidChase no, this is just the Jquery plugin used with a Wordpress loop. However, I did also try out a Wordpress plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nivo-slider-for-wordpress/) and it had the exact same issue.

Comment: when `echo` out `the_field('link')` what does it produce? i dont see how nivo slider would prepend anything its not the goal/objective of the js plugin

Comment: @DavidChase the_field('link') is correctly echoing the link to my target page (the first 4 a.nivo-imageLink tags in my code above). the_field('image') is also correctly echoing the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Within the plugin you can specify an Absolute Path. Wordpress already has this built in with the following code:

```
$wpDir = ABSPATH;
print_r($wpDir) // path to wp install
```

You can see what the displays and then adjust your image path accordingly.

Comment: where can you specify an absolute path in the plugin? I am not using a Wordpress plugin. I did try it with this plugin: wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nivo-slider-for-wordpress with the same bad path results. I'd like to figure out the issue with the Jquery plugin but at this point I'd use anything that will actually *work*!

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the 404 error messages you're getting.

```
http:/www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg
```

The URL is malformed as the scheme is missing an additional forward slash, I suppose this is then being interpreted as a relative URL instead.

Comment: hey, good catch! except that's not what's being pulled from my field. the path coming from my field is this exactly: `http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/product1.jpg` and NOT the malformed address that's missing the forward slash. someplace in this plugin, it is getting stripped...?